# how to use forEach() method in querying firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My problem is regarding querying of a deep-layered real-time database in a firebase cloud functions.

My database structure is somewhat like this:

```
{  
     "sellers":  
        {  
           "s0": {  
                 "customers":    
                           {  
                           "c0":  
                               {
                                "name":"ABC",  
                                "email":"abc@gmail.com",  
                                "phone":"8899889988",  
                                "products":  
                                         {  
                                           "123":
                                                {  
                                               "productname":"WHIRLPOOL MACHINE",  
                                                "dop":"2018-07-03",  
                                                "period":"2"  
                                                 },  
                                           "456":  
                                                 { 
                                                 "productname":"ONIDA OVEN",  
                                                 "dop":"2018-07-04",    
                                                 "period":"1"    
                                                 }  
                                         }  
                                      },  .....and so on
```

Now, in my cloud function ,I wrote a piece of code to get the period of each product for customer(c0),which was like this:

```
exports.testQuery =  functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
  const dates = [];
  ref.child("sellers/s0/customers/c0").once("value").then(snap => {
    const childSnap = snap.val().products;
    childSnap.forEach(grandSnap => {
       const days = grandSnap.val().period;
       dates.push(days);
    });
    return dates;
  }).then(response => res.send(response))
  .catch(error => res.send(error));
});
```

When I deploy the function my expected out should be:

> ["2","1"]

It does not seem to work, whereas I think my logic is correct.
The output I get on the webpage is :

> {}

PLEASE HELP!

> Also, can't ***forEach()*** methods be nested for **this operation on multiple customers and hence multiple sellers**?

Comment: Thats probably one of the biggest problems while using no-sql db. Going through deep docs can end up being a nightmare. You can use forEach only in array like items, you might want to use Object.keys(doc).forEach(key => //do stuff ) and so on for each level.

Comment: @CristianS.   Hi! I see. But how do I get the entire object inside an object? By using Object.keys(obj) we only get the keys of that referenced object in an array format.

Comment: well you iterate through the keys and you still have the object itself dont you?. You just neded to do Object.keys(doc).forEach(key => doc[key] // doc.key is the object property  )

Comment: @CristianS. It helped! Thank you so much! :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your `products` is not an array, so it doesn't have a `forEach`. You should also only load the `products`, since that all you use:

```
const dates = [];
ref.child("sellers/s0/customers/c0/products").once("value").then(snap => {
  snap.forEach(productSnap => {
     const days = productSnap.val().period;
     dates.push(days);
  });
  return dates;
}).then(response => res.send(response))
```